# How do I install Ubuntu from Suse?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, opensuse, system-installation, suse

I just got a new laptop (HP ProBook 4520s), and I don't have my PC here, with which I used to create bootable USB's to install Ubuntu with. I only have an USB, an external hard drive, and some CDs/DVDs, at the moment. So, my question goes, how do I into Ubuntu?

I'm on Suse 11, which came preinstalled, so basically I'm asking how to create a LiveCD/bootable something on Suse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use usb-creator-kde](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/) to transfer the Ubuntu installation ISO to a USB stick. The correct SuSE package name to install is [usb-creator](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=usb-creator&project=home%3ariddell%3ausb-creator).

Answer (score 1):

I did not use it on Suse but I used [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) in the past and it seems to [available for Suse](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?project=openSUSE:11.4%3aContrib&package=unetbootin), too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have CDs then burn a live disk using K3b or brasero.

If you want to create a live USB then download the image and dd it.

[This should help you out.](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aLive_USB_stick#Create_a_Live_USB_.28GUI.29)